# SharePoint 2010 Search Issue after crawled

Tags: search, crawling, search-results, enterprise-search

I've encountered Search issue after content migration from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 by Content Database approach.

actions performed before migration:

- run stsadm -o preupgradecheck  (no issue)
- run Test-SPContentDatabase   (no missing features)
- deployed custom files (.ascx, .aspx and dlls)

After all the content has been migrated to SharePoint 2010, generally no obvious issue and tested pages can be open.

Then I perform full crawl in CA and it was successful, from crawl log able to see there is plenty of pages has been crawled.

However, when I try to perform search, I hit error which no further description except a correlation ID, which no useful information after check in SharePoint log.

My question is, how can I perform troubleshooting to solve the issue above?

Please help, thank you in advanced.

Comment: What is the item count in the Index?  Is the site collection you are searching against mapped to the new Search Service Application?  You may want to try provisioning a new search center anyway in order to take advantage of the refinement panel.

Comment: Did you look up that correlation id in ULS logs?